# browse ipv6 hosts by hostname, instead of ipv6 address

Tags: ipv6, www

Is it possible to browse to ipv6 address by hostname? So instead of http://[2001:888:0:18::80] go to like http://[www.xs4all.nl]. I know this is not working but why is this? To be clear, this is not a question about name resolving.

Comment: Follow up: so I know about RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2732 but trying to understand above question ;)

Comment: I have no idea either? He wants to type a DNS record but it's not about a DNS record

Comment: Try typing the hostname without brackets.

Answer (score 1):

`[ ]` doesn't mean "enable IPv6". The brackets are not a standalone syntax element in URLs – they're only defined as *part of* an IPv6 address, and have no meaning otherwise.

See [RFC 3986 section 3.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2):

```
host       = IP-literal / IPv4address / reg-name
IP-literal = "[" ( IPv6address / IPvFuture  ) "]"
IPvFuture  = "v" 1*HEXDIG "." 1*( unreserved / sub-delims / ":" )
```

According to this syntax, when host starts with a `[` it must be followed either by an IPv6 address, or by `v` indicating some future IP version. When your browser finds some other text instead (e.g. a domain name), it doesn't fit any of the specified options and the whole URL gets rejected as invalid.

Comment: Ah thanks for clearing this out. Am I correct stating that to "enable IPv6", just type in the hostname without brackets, like Nordlys Jeger states? If there's no IPv4 route, automatically the connection is made over IPv6?

Comment: Yes, the client will use IPv6 if it's available. (Most programs _prefer_ IPv6 if it is available and only use IPv4 otherwise. Web browsers tend to use both simultaneously and stick with whichever address answers faster.)